# Fall grade reporting

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

Some programs require fall grades (which I'm happy about, mine are good).
However, some neither require it, nor do they have the ability to upload them through the online app.
Should I email someone on the grad admission committee something along the lines of:

Hi,

greetings and thanks for opportunity to submit my app and thank you for the time you take to read my app

rewording the text above^^^

happy holidays, thank you

Thoughts?

Comment: I assume that they don't actually want them. They probably wouldn't know what to do with them in this circumstance. Why bother?

Comment: Are you asking if you should submit/ have our university send an updated transcript?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use "app" as shorthand for "application" in this context.

Comment: Hi all! Thank you for the comments. One step in the graduate school application process is to update our unofficial transcripts. Some schools ask that when we receive our fall grades, we update that unofficial transcript. Hope this helps explain what I'm asking :) Since my grades have improved (albeit from 3.93 to 3.94) I think it would pay to at least ask the programs/ or at least the department to which I'm applying, if they would like they.

Answer (score 2):

**You should never submit your grades directly**

Students should never be in charge of submitting their own grades or recommendation letters to programs (I'm assuming you mean graduate program).  The risk of cheating would be extremely high, and your current university is almost certainly well-versed in sending (and receiving) grades in a safe, secure way.

Comment: Hi Sevensevens! Please see my comment above! While you are correct about letters of recommendation, I have not encountered one school/program thus far that does not accept unofficial transcripts. While some do require us to mail official transcripts, most allow unofficial until you are offered a spot — then you must submit your official transcript prior to matriculation. Hope this helps!

Comment: If they told you to send them, then go ahead.  I was able to digitally send a copy of my transcripts when I applied, and I assumed this was the same across the board.  As long as they verify the transcripts after, you probably couldn't forge anything, but why have to do the work twice?